# PgAdmin4 на Linux Mint 18.2 32bit

Tags: pgadmin4

Возможно ли поставить PgAdmin4 на Linux Mint 18.2 32bit?

Пробовала разные способы (pip install, sudo apt install..) не получается - всегда ошибки разного характера.

На Linux Mint 19.3 64bit PgAdmin4 установился нормально без проблем.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемой и ее разрешением?

Answer (score 0):

Должна работать команда:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

Comment: То же самое, что и на обычном install. При запуске pgadmin4 возникает ошибка "The pgAdmin4 server could not be contacted". В логах "...INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.." (sudo не помогает)

Comment: @МарияБорцова https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211296/pgadmin4-postgresql-application-server-could-not-be-contacted